# Python NameError, works fine on other machines

Tags: python

I have a weird python NameError that is confounding me, and completely stopping the work on the project I am working on.  When I run the code on my machine running python 2.7.1 I get a NameError, but a coworker can run the code fine on his machine.  The indentation is all spaces around the line the error occurs as well.  Here's the code

```
"""File: GatoTest.py"""  
""" bunch of imports """
from Gato import *

def usage():
  """irrelevant code"""
  app = AlgoWin()
```

And the code in Gato does include a class AlgoWin with an empty constructor

```
class AlgoWin(Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent=None, graph_panes=None, paned=False, experimental=False):
    """irrelevant code"""
```

The error is thrown on the line app=AlgoWin(), and the exact message is

NameError: name 'AlgoWin' is not defined

I'm at a complete loss at this point, thanks in advance for any help or direction.

Comment: If you `import Gato` from the Python CLI, what's the value of `dir(Gato)` afterwards?

Comment: Run the program with `python -v` to see which files are actually used.

Comment: Try printing out `locals`, `globals`, and `dir(Gato)` and seeing if something similar is there? A cursory google search shows no results for AlgoWin, so it might be part of an internal API? If you're looking at source code, try `grep`ing for `del AlgoWin`?

Comment: dir(Gato) only gives me ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__'], does that seem right?

Comment: @Smerk: That is definitely not right.  You should see `'Algowin'` in that list.  Is it possible you have another module also named `Gato` somewhere on your python path?  It's either that or the module is not installed properly.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski-- I just checked, that is the only Gato I have.  As for the module not being installed properly, if it is a class defined within Gato.py then is there anyway that it wouldn't be installed properly?  Sorry if this is basic stuff, still learning the ins and outs of python

Comment: Turns out there was another Gato hiding in there after all!  I don't know how that happened, but may have been an svn mistake or something.  Thanks for helping out, I would've been tearing my hair out for another few hours without you guys!

Comment: Those crazy cats always hide so well.

Comment: Unpredictable errors are why you should never ever ever use `import *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like the import isn't importing the right code. Try using `from Gato import AlgoWin` (which is better practice anyway); you'll probably get an `ImportError` there.

Have you moved `Gato.py`? Check for any stray `.pyc` files that might be confusing the interpreter.

Comment: I tried the direct import of AlgoWin, and it does indeed give an ImportError.  Gato.py is in the right location, and deleting it's .pyc file didn't fix it unfortunately.  Gatotest.py hasn't been run on my machine yet so there isn't a .pyc

Comment: @Smerk:  It's possible you have another `Gato.py` somewhere that is being imported instead.

Comment: That was it, there was a complete project folder within the main folder.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `Gato.py` (or `Gato.pyc`) in your source tree that it shadowing the `Gato` you want to import?

Is the output of `import Gato; print Gato.__file__` what you expect?